# redhat/bash - two equals scripts, one get "command not found" error

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, scripting, command-not-found

I did write two scripts, where one has part simple code of the other ones and several comments in:

user : oracle
both files are of oracle.
both files have the execution clearance on : chmod +x fpc.sh && chmod +x bpc.sh

script that works: fpc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# author bla bla bla
#
ORACLE_SID=MyOracleSid
PATH=/app/oracle/admin/DB/$1
TARGHET="\/app\/oracle\/admin\/DB\/$1"
chmod -R 755 $PATH

find $PATH -type f -exec egrep 'ORACLE_SID' {} \; -print
```

script that doesn't works: bpc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# author bla bla bla
#
ORACLE_SID=MyOracleSid
PATH=/app/oracle/admin/DB/$1
#
#TARGHET="\/app\/oracle\/admin\/DB\/$1"
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
chmod -R 755 $PATH

find $PATH -type f -exec egrep 'ORACLE_SID' {} \; -print
```

bpc.sh gets:

chmod command not found
find        command not found

How is possible?

thanks for your collaboration,

Comment: Value next to  PATH=  made system not able to find `chmod` and `find`

Comment: I don't believe you that the first one "works".

Comment: @glenn jackman,  neither do I, unless $1 was defined to something reasoneable and was passed to the script

Comment: Both scripts cannot work. Well, they did partially work with `bosh` since bosh has a builtin `find` program based on `libfind`.

Comment: A cheeky comment: it will work fine if you call it like `./bpc.sh ":$PATH"`

Comment: The environment variable `PATH` has a very specific use for the shell, changing it has consequences to find commands.

Answer (score 1):

This is why using `CAPS` for variable names in Bash is a **really bad idea**.

If you had used `snake_case` or `CamelCase`, you would not have altered the environmental variable `PATH`.

Ergo:

```
path=/app/oracle/admin/DB/$1
```

is ok

```
PATH=/app/oracle/admin/DB/$1
```

is not.

Run

```
( set -o posix ; set )
```

to see just ow many variables you can mistakingly override with `CAPS` variables. Instead of trying to keep track of them, just take it as a general rule to **not** use `CAPS`.

Comment: I would like to say to all excuse me for this post.